# Core WLAN MCS Index?

Tags: swift, macos, corewlan

I'm trying to recreate the information displayed for the current Wi-Fi network when option-clicking on the Wi-Fi status bar item.  One of the parameters shown is the MCS Index, but I can't find any way to query this value using the `CWInterface` class, which is where I am getting most of the other data:

```
if let interface = CWWiFiClient.shared().interface() {
    rssi = interface.rssiValue()
    noise = interface.noiseMeasurement()
    // etc.
}
```

Since both the Wi-Fi status bar item and the airport command line tool display the MCS Index, it seems like there should be some way to query it:

```
MacBook:~ mark$ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I
     agrCtlRSSI: -46
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -90
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station 
     lastTxRate: 878
        maxRate: 1300
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa2-psk
          BSSID: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
           SSID: MyWiFi
            MCS: 7
        channel: 149,80
```

I've also seem some [Python sample code](https://gist.github.com/chilcote/10010307) that seems to indicate that the MCS Index should be available, but I don't see it in the docs or code completion.

Is there some way to get this value through Core WLAN or some other framework, or is this something I need to calculate based on other values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another Python script [wifi_status.py](https://gist.github.com/isometry/a0313976e0cc642dc1611414f24f462b/)
which reports the WiFi status. From the lines

```
def wifi_status(properties=('bssid', 'channel', 'txRate', 'mcsIndex', 'rssi', 'noise')):
    xface = CWWiFiClient.sharedWiFiClient().interface()
    while True:
        yield({name: getattr(xface, name)() for name in properties})
```

one can conclude that these attributes can be retrieved with
Key-Value Coding.

And that really works:

```
if let iface = CWWiFiClient.shared().interface() {
    if let mcsIndex = iface.value(forKey: "mcsIndex") as? Int {
        print(mcsIndex)
    }
}
```

But I have now idea if that approach is officially supported,
or will work in the future, so use at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly for my use.  One question... is it possible to catch the error if the "mcsIndex" property is ever removed?  If I put in a non-existent key, I get a "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mcsIndexX" error and can't work out how to continue with a default value (I have `var mcs: Int = data.value(forKey: "mcsIndexX") as? Int ?? -1` at the moment).  Sorry, Swift noob here!

Comment: @Mark: `if iface.responds(to: Selector(("mcsIndex")))` should work.